# How to join .txt-files without importing?

Tags: files-and-directories

Is it possible to write a code, telling MMA to join 2 (or even more) .txt-files without importing them?

Comment: Something like `cat` then?

Comment: @J.M. hmm, don't know what cat means, except a pet...

Comment: `cat` is Unix-style command line command

Comment: sounds like this is what I mean, as I can force MMA to rename files, I thought this joining might also work somehow. Looks like there is no such command, isn't there?

Comment: cat: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)
`Run`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html

Could be a goer?

Comment: what means goer?

Comment: Sorry, colloquialism, here it means "a possible route".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have two files 1.txt and 2.txt. You open your terminal, go to the folder and type

> cat 1.txt 2.txt > new.txt

It will give you a new file `new.txt` combining the content of 1.txt and 2.txt

But this is not an answer for mathematica community. Lets do the same thing with mathematica.

First I shall create several files.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Do[Export[ToString[i] <> ".txt", {Join[ConstantArray["blah", i], {"\n"}]}, "Table"], {i, 7}]
```

Now I have 7 files to combine. I am going to create the bash command for `cat` and then `Run` it.

```
com = "cat ";
Do[com = com <> ToString[i] <> ".txt ", {i, 7}]
com = com <> " > out.txt"
Run[com]
```

Now you have a file `out.txt` will everything.

Comment: This kind of still isn't an answer for the MMA community and cat is platform specific.

Comment: I agree @LLlAMnYP, but this is the best I can do with MMA without importing the file :| .

Answer (score 3):

```
Run["cat file1.txt file2.txt > newfile.txt"]
```

But be sure to set your working directory to the folder with the files in first:

```
SetDirectory["~/Desktop/Text Cat"]
```